# this code is not working?can anyone tell me why?

Tags: jquery

iam working on a web project..this is my jquery code..i tried several times and this code is not working..

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  "use strict";

  $('#slider-carousel').carouFredSel({
    responsive:true,
    width:'100%',
    circular:true,
    scroll:{
      items:1,
      duration:700,
      pauseOnHover: true
    },
    auto:true,
    items:{
      visible:{
        min:1,
        max:1
      },
      height:"variable"
     },
  });

});
```

Comment: Why are you specifying `"use strict";` inside `jQuery(document).ready(function(){`?? Put that line of code at the top of your javascript file

Comment: @papji press f12 tell me what error it has

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal: It's fine where it is, if the OP only wants it applied within that function and/or all the code is within that function.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal; we can put the "use strict"; inside the $(function(){ ... }), and it's not an error

Comment: Please read [ask]. Your question lacks pretty much everything that is mentioned in there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you've a comma after

height:"variable"}

I'm not sure (I cannot verify), but it looks wrong.

Comment: the comma is not the error, it is not correct putting comma after the last element of object or an array, but it will not be an error

Answer (score 0):

in the document of plugin
there is no value of height equal to "variable"
and the values of height either "auto" or in "px" or %"

> try change the the value of height

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  "use strict";

  $('#slider-carousel').carouFredSel({
    responsive:true,
    width:'100%',
    circular:true,
    scroll:{
      items:1,
      duration:700,
      pauseOnHover: true
    },
    auto:true,
    items:{
      visible:{
        min:1,
        max:1
      },
      height:"auto"
     }
  });

});
```

you can read the index.html of the plugin

> https://github.com/Codeinwp/carouFredSel-jQuery/blob/master/index.html